# Android: Resample bitmap as zooming in?

Tags: android, imageview, zooming

I have some large images that I would like to display to the user.   I want them to have the ability to zoom in.   I am currently using TouchImageView, and it is working, however, the quality/resolution of the image does not change as I zoom in.

I noticed that some of the Gallery apps appear to be doing this.   They load the entire image, at some sampling rate so that it can be displayed without an out of memory.  Then as you zoom in, it appears that the quality of the image is getting increased.

Is there example code/library for functionality similar to this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have 1 source image and are zooming in on it you aren't going to magically create resolution where there was none previously.  The answer is to either create multiple r-sets or multiple images with different resolutions and load/zoom/scale dynamically, OR downsample the image yourself when displaying it zoomed out at a lower resolution.

For example, consider thumbnail images.  They are created as a small sample of the original image.  If you zoomed in on that thumbnail it would look horrible.  You calculate the best r-set image based on the zoom level and coordinates of your client view.

I think my preference would be to preprocess the large images and create different levels of resolution as I mentioned in the first paragraph.  Then as the user zooms in you load a different image.  This is similar to how Google maps works for example.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was thinking of...starting with a high-res image and resampling it as the user zoomed in.  (I hadn't thought of preprocessing the image at different sample rates prior, probably would perform better).  I guess I thought this would be a very common problem, that someone has already solved, and made a library available.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use the view provided by Dave Morrissey:

[Subsampling Scale Image View](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view)

An excerpt from the source:

> A custom ImageView for Android with pinch to zoom and subsampled tiles
>   to support large images. While zooming in, the low resolution, full
>   size base layer is overlaid with smaller tiles in the best resolution
>   for the current scale, and tiles are loaded and discarded during
>   panning to avoid holding too much bitmap data in memory.